# Change text track (subtitle) language during casting does not work

Tags: chromecast

In order to be able to change language of subtitles during casting, Media Track has been implemented according to:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced

At sender side, it seems to work out fine. However, the receiver does not respond to text track languages changes made at the sender side during casting. The sender uses cast V3 and the reciever is a "Custom reciever V2". Default text track works fine.

Any suggestion how I can debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver), it is strongly recommended to use [CAF Receiver SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_overview) instead of the current version you are using.

> **Version warning:** For new development, you should absolutely use the
>   [CAF Receiver SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_overview) instead of this Receiver v2 SDK. If you have an
>   existing integration, we encourage you to migrate to CAF Receiver SDK
>   for benefits that CAF offers.